# Laravel 5.0 Create Separate Login Functionality

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I am attempting to create a separate login function for admins and standard users.  What I mean by this is that admins will use the standard name and email to log in whereas standard users must use an id(not table id), DoB and meeting date to log in.  Now, my question(s) is this: where do I find the files to modify to implement this functionality?  Can I override it on the AuthController.php instead of modifying the vender files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the AuthController / create your own and / or the Middleware class that handles the authentication.

Comment: I shall try to duplicate the AuthController and I can get it working(already have most of the base AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.php functions overwritten).  Thanks.